# Why/Should we implement BaseColumns when using a Content Provider in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I was browsing the source code for Google [IOSched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) App and noticed the following code snippet as part of their Content Provider implementation:

`public static class Blocks implements BlocksColumns, BaseColumns`.

As far as I know [BaseColumns](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html) is simply an interface to two constants: `_COUNT` and `_ID`.

I have two questions:

1. What are the advantages/disadvantages of the implementing BaseColumns as opposed to having  a private field `_ID` in the class directly?
2. What is the role of the constant `_COUNT`?

Comment: #1 looks like an anti-pattern to me. I use BaseColumns like a constant class, so use BaseColumns._ID directly in my code instead.

Answer (score 23):

According to the [Android Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html),

> Note: A provider isn't required to have a primary key, and it isn't
>   required to use _ID as the column name of a primary key if one is
>   present. However, if you want to bind data from a provider to a
>   ListView, one of the column names has to be _ID. This requirement is
>   explained in more detail in the section Displaying query results.

The Guide continues on to explain the basics of why you need a unique value provided by the `primary key`,

> Table data should always have a "primary key" column that the provider
>   maintains as a unique numeric value for each row. You can use this
>   value to link the row to related rows in other tables (using it as a
>   "foreign key"). Although you can use any name for this column, using
>   BaseColumns._ID is the best choice, **because linking the results of a
>   provider query to a ListView requires one of the retrieved columns to
>   have the name _ID.**
>   [emphasis mine]

To answer your questions in the order that you provided them:

1. Having the `_ID` Column is a best practice for versatility.  It doesn't have to be displayed, but works terrific as the primary key (and foreign key!) Required for cursors and queries.

   - Having it identified by BaseColumns automatically identifies this column as the primary key, unique (obviously), and instructs it to autoincrement.
   - Presumably, implementing BaseColumns is easier than typing out these properties for your private fields.
2. `_COUNT` [is just the count of the number of rows in a directory.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html#_COUNT)  If your table's rows are being deleted and added, there is no reason to believe that an item's `_ID` integer has anything to do with when it was added or its sort properties. In other words, `last_insert_rowid()` **DOES NOT EQUAL** `Count()`.  The _COUNT column just provides a way to show how many results are returned on a query, IN EVERY LINE of that query. For a visual reference, see [linuxtopia.org](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: What if i have multiple tables and tables have primary key say `note_table` have note_id and `book_table` have book_id how do i use BaseColumns._ID there??

Comment: @VikasRathod Just implement BaseColumns to setup the schema, <http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html>. Instead of `FeedEntry`, create a new class for each table implementing `BaseColumns`  It won't be a problem that you have two fields called "ID" because one will really be "book_ID" and the other will be "note_ID."  Each table will have a primary key, but *not necessarily* a foreign key.

Answer (score -3):

No real reason to use it...you can ignore it totally and use your own definitions of `_ID` and `_COUNT` (if u need)...