# What is the use of BaseColumns in Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

What is the use of implementing a class from `BaseColumns` in Android?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is a simple interface which adds two fields :

```
public interface BaseColumns
{
    /**
     * The unique ID for a row.
     * <P>Type: INTEGER (long)</P>
     */
    public static final String _ID = "_id";

    /**
     * The count of rows in a directory.
     * <P>Type: INTEGER</P>
     */
    public static final String _COUNT = "_count";
}
```

Internally sqlite databases used in Android, comes with an  `_id` column that autoincrements and can function as a primary key. This also maps well with the `ContentProviders`

Answer (score 66):

The [`BaseColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html) interface provides names for the very common `_ID` and `_COUNT` columns.

Using common names enables the Android platform (and developers as well) to address any data item, regardless of its overall structure (i.e. other, non-ID columns) in a unified way. Defining constants for commonly used strings in an interface/class avoids repetition and typos all over the code.

Using a column named `_id` (the constant value of `BaseColumns._ID`) is required by [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html), implementations of a [`ContentProvider`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and other places where you hand off a `Cursor` to the Android platform to do things for you. For example, the adapter of a `ListView` uses the `_ID` column to give you the unique ID of the list item clicked in [`OnItemClickListener.onItemClick()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick%28android.widget.AdapterView%3C?%3E,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29), without you having to explicitly specify what your ID column is every time.

Whether or not to **implement** interfaces consisting only of constants or **reference** them with their full name, i.e. `BaseColumns._ID` is a matter of taste. I *personally* prefer the latter, because it's more obvious where `_ID` is coming from and the former feels like an abuse of inheritance.

Comment: **thnx**
so it means we do not have to fetch the id (that is primary key) of table , its autmaticaly available from BaseColumns._ID

Comment: You still have to fetch the ID column in your `SELECT` queries, `BaseColumns._ID` only defines the *name* of that ID column.

Comment: whatever is the name of primary id column is replace by BaseColumns._ID at query compilation. is it right?

Comment: The value of `BaseColumns._ID`, i.e. the string `"_id"`, *is* the name of the primary ID column; the primary ID column can't have any other name if you want to use it with `CusorAdapter`, `ContentProvider`, `ListView`, etc.

Comment: It came to me that maybe proper use of "BaseColumns._ID" in NOT to have column with this name in every table but rather create a column ALIAS with this name for every SQL SELECT statement to be fed to CursorAdapter etc. ?! From the Database structure point of view having the same column name with different meanings (semantics) is not a good pattern. E.g. it is much clearer to use UserID with the "ID of the User" meaning in every table including the "User" table...

Comment: Indeed, there's no need to actually name a *table* column after `BaseColumns._ID`, it's just an easy way to get a *result* column with that name for `CursorAdapter`/`ContentProvider`.

Comment: Okay, but what's _COUNT for, 'the count of rows in a directory'?

Comment: @Maarten "Every provider can also report the number of records returned as the _COUNT column; its value is the same for all rows." from the section "What a query returns" of http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Also relevant for `_COUNT` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/12946061/1276636

Answer (score 1):

The BaseColumn interface only provides the column *names* _ID and _COUNT.  You must still specify columns that use them when constructing tables.  For example, to create a column using the column name _ID you might do the following:

```
public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
    "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
    + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
    + USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
    + EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE)";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an interface, which looks like this

```
public interface BaseColumns
{

    public static final String _ID = "_id";


    public static final String _COUNT = "_count";
}
```

It contains constants like id and count used for auto-increment in SQL lite DB.

We can also create our own constants for id without using this particular interface. But functions like cursor adaptor requires the exact constants like "_id", So it is better to use the provided interface!!

Hope this helps you out!! :-)