# use of BaseColumns or not with ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

what is the difference between using **BaseColumns** or not with a *ContentProvider*? It's an *interface*, so it might be used somewhere else...? I don't really get the point, i'm using simple constants in my *Content Provider* to define the `_id` or the `name` in my database, and it works just fine. So, am i missing something?

> public static final class Notes implements BaseColumns { ...

thanks

ps: i've checked this answer : [What is the use of BaseColumns in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899720/what-is-the-use-of-basecolumns-in-android) but i can't really see the point with the answers posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of implementing BaseColumns is the same as the point of reusing any code whatsoever; you don't **have** to reuse code, you can re-implement it again, the question is: what for?

Now, in the case of BaseColumns this does not stand out so much because, obviously, all they provide is a constant for two columns (_ID and _COUNT), so you don't save **that** much time implementing BaseColumns instead of just adding these two constants yourself. But why not use it if you can?

**tl;dr:** You don't have to use BaseColumns if you don't want to, all it does is save you from typing a few lines of code. On the other hand: since it does save you from typing them, why not use it?

Comment: thanks Seramme, can you tell me what BaseColumns actually does? i mean, does the contentprovider call BaseColumns if you implement it?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. It doesn't even define any methods, so there is nothing to call. All it is is a container for two constants. You could as well not implement it in your ContentProvider but in another class and use ThatOtherClass._ID to reference the id column. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html