# Android - BaseColumns and _id

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I was reading this thread: [What is the use of BaseColumns in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899720/what-is-the-use-of-basecolumns-in-androi), and I get how to use BaseColumns, that you have to fetch _id in your SELECT statements.

What's still unclear to me is when is the _id field "internally" created? Is it during execSQL(...) that Android adds the _id field? Or, do we still have to define it in the CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: As far as I know, you need to create it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must create it "manually". Android won't do that for you.

For example, during table creation, you issue:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, timestamp INTEGER, message TEXT);
```

See? The `_id` column is explicitly named and added.

Or, following the convention of DB-helper classes you'll come up with something like that:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MESSAGES + " ("
        + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + COLUMN_TIMESTAMP + " INTEGER,"
        + COLUMN_MESSAGE + " TEXT"
        + ");");
```

where the `TABLE_*` and `COLUMN_*` are constant fields of DB-helper, e.g.:

```
public static final String TABLE_MESSAGES = "messages";
public static final String COLUMN_TIMESTAMP = "timestamp";
public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE = "message";
```

Comment: As far as I understand it's best practice to have TABLE_* and COLUMN_* constant fields as inner abstract static classes of a class that's used to describe the schema: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#DefineContract