# Android - Can't create instance of Database

Tags: android, database, sqliteopenhelper

I am following [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#WriteDbRow) tutorial made by our folks over at Google.

If you look at the third code snippet, the tutorial shows the `FeedReaderDbHelper` class which extends from the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class.

```
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

Then, it shows how to create an instance of the `FeedReaderDbHelper` object in order to use it to read and write to the database.

```
FeedReaderDbHelper mDbHelper = new FeedReaderDbHelper(getContext());
```

The problem as I see it is that `SQLiteOpenHelper` is an abstract class. So whenever I do the following in my *own* program:

`MatchEntry.MatchDBHelper dbHelper = new MatchEntry.MatchDBHelper(context);`

I get an error: `....MatchContract.MatchEntry is not an enclosing class`

Is this because of `SQLiteOpenHelper` being abstract? The way I have set-up my classes are *exactly* the same and pretty much mimic exactly what the docs have.

**Update**

This is how the structure looks like so far:

```
public class MatchContract {

    public MatchContract() {
    }

    public static abstract class MatchEntry implements BaseColumns {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }

    public class MatchDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Am I correct to put the `MatchDBHelper` inside the `MatchContract` class? I assume so as it needs to know the `SQL_CREATE_TABLE` string, otherwise it won't know.

Comment: `MatchDBHelper` can't be an inner class, I think. I also did that tutorial. Here you have it, take a look. You will see contract is separated from the sqlHelper class: https://github.com/algui91/CursoAndroid/tree/master/Ejemplos/PersistenciaDeDatos/src/com/tformacion/persistenciadedatos

Comment: @algui91 - Ahah ok. So will I have to create a `DBHelper` for every entry? For example: `StudentDBHelper`, `ClassDBHelper`, `CarDBHelper`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is, that a `Contract` class is an abstraction of the database, So, in `MatchContract` you will have all the global variables of the database and in the inner class, `MatchEntry` you will implement the abstraction of the database itself (columns etc). Then, with `MatchDBHelper` you will be managing the database (Creating it, upgrading it etc) And writing SQL entries.

As I said in the comments, You need to create the helper class as a normal class, not an inner class:

```
public class MatchContract {

public MatchContract() {
}

/// Global variables for the DB

    public static abstract class MatchEntry implements BaseColumns {
    // Structure of the database
    }
}


public class MatchDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Manage the database
}
```

As a complete example:

```
public final class PersonContract {

    public PersonContract() {
    }
    public static abstract class PersonEntry implements BaseColumns{
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "person";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "personID";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_FIRST_NAME = "firstname";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SECOND_NAME = "secondname";
    }
}

public class PersonDbBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Persons.db";

    private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
    private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + PersonEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    PersonEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + // Heredado de BaseColumns
                    PersonEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    PersonEntry.COLUMN_NAME_FIRST_NAME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                    PersonEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SECOND_NAME + TEXT_TYPE  +
                    " )";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + PersonEntry.TABLE_NAME;


    public PersonDbBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @algui91. Can you please tell me if i have to create a DBHelper for every entry? For example: StudentDBHelper, ClassDBHelper, CarDBHelper?

Comment: @Subby You need to create a DBHelper per database, not per table.

Comment: Ah right, so I will need to extend the SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES so that it includes ALL tables which I have?

Comment: @Subby I think it will be more organised have one SQL_CREATE per table, and then in `onCreate` do `db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE1); db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE2);`... I never create a database in android with more than one table, but I think this is a good approach.

Comment: One more question please. If the `FeedEntry` object extends from `BaseColumns` then why does it have it's own `COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID` since the `BaseColumns` class has it's own ID?

Comment: From developer.android: Note: By implementing the BaseColumns interface, your inner class can inherit a primary key field called _ID that some Android classes such as cursor adaptors will expect it to have. It's not required, but this can help your database work harmoniously with the Android framework.

Comment: So in other words I can use that as the ID? I don't have to create my own?

Comment: @Subby Yes, but check this answer for further details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7900591/1612432