# Storing primary key values in SQLite database in android using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a form which asks values like name, gender etc. These values are stored in a table with a primary key field Id which is not entered by the user. I have to enter it with incrementing its value every time a new record is saved by using SharedPreferences. How do I do that?

This is my class file:

```
saveBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save);
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        String name             = nameEdt.getText().toString().trim();
        String trainingTypes    = trainingTypesSpn.toString().trim();
        String trainerProfile   = trainerProfileSpn.toString().trim();
        String description      = descriptionEdt.toString().trim();
        String plannedBudget    = plannedBudgetNp.toString().trim();
        String startDt          = startDtEdt.toString().trim();
        String endDt            = endDtEdt.toString().trim();

        TrainingDetailsDTO dto = new TrainingDetailsDTO();

        dto.setName(name);
        dto.setTrainingTypes(trainingTypes);
        dto.setTrainerProfile(trainerProfile);
        dto.setDescription(description);
        dto.setPlannedBudget(plannedBudget);
        dto.setStartDt(startDt);
        dto.setEndDt(endDt);

        SQLiteDatabase database = DBHandler.getInstance(mActivity).getDBObject(1);
        boolean isInsert = TrainingDetailsDAO.getInstance().insert(dto, database);

        if (isInsert)
        {

            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mActivity.popFragments();
            mActivity.pushFragments(Constants.TAB_HOUSE, new HouseConstructionTrack(), false, false);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Insert Problem", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        mActivity.popFragments();
    }
});
```

This is my insert method in DAO class:

```
public boolean insert(DTO dtoObject, SQLiteDatabase dbObject)
{
    TrainingDetailsDTO dto = (TrainingDetailsDTO) dtoObject;

    ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
    cValues.put("TrainingDetailsId", "TR001"); 
    cValues.put("name"          ,   dto.getName());
    cValues.put("trainingTypes" ,   dto.getTrainingTypes());
    cValues.put("trainerProfile",   dto.getTrainerProfile());
    cValues.put("description"   ,   dto.getDescription());
    cValues.put("plannedBudget" ,   dto.getPlannedBudget());
    cValues.put("startDt"       ,   dto.getStartDt());
    cValues.put("endDt"         ,   dto.getEndDt());

    dbObject.insert("TRAINING_DETAILS", null, cValues);

    return false;
}
```

Here I am only able to give Id for the first record. How to generate subsequent Ids using SharedPreferences?

Comment: This will help you... [link](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) check this..

Comment: Actually, my Id is of the form TR001, TR002, TR003 etc. When a new record is added it should be incremented to TR004 and stored into the database alongwith the other values. I have to use SharedPreferences here. But, I don't know how.

Comment: Then you should handle with code only while you submit data to database increment your id value according to your need and save it..

Comment: Consider storing database keys in the database itself and using the regular `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` autogeneration there. If you need a special format for some other purpose, do the formatting outside the database.

Answer (score 1):

Extend BaseColumns in Android. It automatically has _ID field which is incremented automatically.

```
public static abstract class User implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TOKEN = "token";
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899720/what-is-the-use-of-basecolumns-in-android