# How can (or should) I map `BaseColumns._ID` to `ROWID`, `_ROWID_`, or `OID`?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm using `BaseColumns` to create a databases with sqlite on Android.
This class comes with a final variable `_ID = "_id";` to (I think) standardize the name of a column of row id's [SO answer about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899720/what-is-the-use-of-basecolumns-in-android). However sqlite usually does not need this, since it internally maintains a row id, accessible as any other column through the names `ROWID`, `_ROWID_`, or `OID`.

For me, it seems logic to map `BaseColumns._ID` to one of this virtual columns, however since its a final variable, I don't see a straightforward approach.

How can (or should) I map `BaseColumns._ID` to `ROWID`, `_ROWID_`, or `OID`?

**EDIT:** According to sqlite documentation:

> "If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that column becomes an alias for the ROWID. You can then access the ROWID using any of four different names, the original three names described above or the name given to the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column. All these names are aliases for one another and work equally well in any context."

And so, explicitly declaring an INTEGER PRIMARY column would be a duplication.

Comment: android requires a `_id` column for cursor adapters and a few other things. You don't need to map it to anything, just use it as your primary key, and it will be aliased automatically. You don't have anything to do. (typically `CREATE TABLE foo (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bar TEXT);`)

Comment: If your table doesn't contain an `_id` field, you can use `SELECT rowID AS _id, ...` and that's it.

Comment: @DerGol...lum, the point is that according to sqlite documentation, a  explicitly declaration of an INTEGER PRIMARY column is an alias to rowid (see quote in comment to CL. answer). And so  I would be duplicating columns.

Comment: @DerGol...lum, of course it works. The point here is that it duplicates the column. I would have _ID and ROWID. Why do that?

Comment: **RowID** is automatically inserted by SQLite. Then I don't understand why did you add the `_id` extra field.

Comment: @DerGol...lum, I didn't. I'm using BaseColumns to create a databases with sqlite on Android. This class comes with a final variable _ID = "_id";

Comment: What's the question, then? Simply assign `BaseColumns._ID = cursor.cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex("rowid"));`

Comment: It's a final variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alias is just another name to a column, it won't duplicate any data.

This means that creating an "_id" column with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY in Sqlite will not duplicate any data, as this will be "mapped" to rowid (i.e., will be an alias).

There is at least one **difference** between the "_id" alias and a regular alias (as pointed out by CL., quoting Sqlite documentation): "The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.". So creating an "_id" column with INTEGER PRIMARY KEY will prevent this column from being changed with a VACUUM command.

Answer (score 3):

The `rowid`s might be maintained internally, but they can change, e.g. when doing [VACUUM](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html).

To ensure that you have stable IDs, you should explicitly declare an INTEGER PRIMARY column — and then you can just use the name `_id` for it.

Comment: According to the documentation: "If a table contains a column of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then that column becomes an alias for the ROWID. You can then access the ROWID using any of four different names, the original three names described above or the name given to the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column. All these names are aliases for one another and work equally well in any context."
In other words, explicitly declare an INTEGER PRIMARY column is the same as not doing it.

Comment: Did you read the page I linked to? "The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. "

Comment: Yes, but according to the quote I pasted, INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias to ROWIDs, meaning VACUUM will also change that.

Comment: It might be an alias, but it's *explicit*.

Comment: Row IDs in an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column do not change. If there is no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, they can change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83322/discussion-between-fernando-cesar-and-cl).

Comment: If you use BIGINT instead of INTEGER, then SQLite does not automatically map the 'rowid' to your alias column.