# Inserting Multiple records in a database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

`enter code here`Am making an application that displays a list of items in a listview and a button to add more items to the listview , and I want to insert those new items to the SQLite database using the same button .

I created a table with 2 Colons (ID , ITEM1 ) Like this :

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
           " ITEM1 TEXT) ";

    db.execSQL(createTable);

}
```

but when i added 3 more Colons to the table , i could not insert any data to the database !!

I tried to search for solutions but didn't get any chance Well Am a Beginner in SQLite and its Confusing me, how can I solve this?

here is the

**Database.java**

```
package com.example.bilel.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME ="foodlist.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME="foodlist_data";
public static final String COL1 = "ID";
public static final String COL2 = "ITEM1";
public static final String COL3 = "CAL1";
public static final String COL4 = "PRO1";
public static final String COL5 = "CARB1";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    /*String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +

            " ITEM1 TEXT) ";*/
    String createTable = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            COL1 + "ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            COL2 + "TEXT NOT NULL,"+
            COL3 + "INTEGER NOT NULL,"+
            COL4 + "INTEGER NOT NULL,"+
            COL5 + "INTEGER NOT NULL);";


    db.execSQL(createTable);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

    ///Add new row to the database
public  boolean additems (String item,int C,int P,int R){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COL2,item);
    values.put(COL3,C );
    values.put(COL4,P);
    values.put(COL5,R);


    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);

    if (result==-1){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }

}
public void clearDatabase(String TABLE_NAME) {
    String clearDBQuery = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(clearDBQuery);
}
public int LastInsert() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT MAX(" + COL1 + ") FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null);
    cur.moveToFirst();
    int ID = cur.getInt(0);
    cur.close();
    return ID;
}
public void LastDelete(){
    //String clearROW = "DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME "WHERE " = "(SELECT MAX(id) FROM notes)";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long id = LastInsert();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME,COL1+"=?",new String[]{Long.toString(id)});
    db.close();
}
public Cursor getListContents(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


    Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);

    return data;

}

}
```

Crash Log

```
11-23 13:56:02.746 3926-3926/com.example.bilel.myapplication E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEfoodlist_data": syntax error
11-23 13:56:02.746 3926-3926/com.example.bilel.myapplication D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
11-23 13:56:02.747 3926-3926/com.example.bilel.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.bilel.myapplication, PID: 3926
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bilel.myapplication/com.example.bilel.myapplication.CalculatorActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEfoodlist_data": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEfoodlist_data (ID ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ITEM1 TEXT NOT NULL,CAL1 INTEGER NOT NULL,PRO1 INTEGER NOT NULL,CARB1 INTEGER NOT NULL);
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                            Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "TABLEfoodlist_data": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLEfoodlist_data (ID ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,ITEM1 TEXT NOT NULL,CAL1 INTEGER NOT NULL,PRO1 INTEGER NOT NULL,CARB1 INTEGER NOT NULL);
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
                                                                               at com.example.bilel.myapplication.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:42)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                                               at com.example.bilel.myapplication.DatabaseHelper.getListContents(DatabaseHelper.java:94)
                                                                               at com.example.bilel.myapplication.CalculatorActivity.onCreate(CalculatorActivity.java:78)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Did you uninstall and install the app (or cleared data) after you added the new rows?

Comment: Am using AVD , so I think no I didn't reinstall the app , for data clearing I have a method that clear the last added item

Comment: You didn't understand what I meant! When you add new rows into your database, the method that creates the database is not called because your database is already created. If you could magically look at the table you have inside the emulator now, it would be the one you created in the very beginning with only TWO columns!
What I mean is uninstall the app and install it, this will solve the issue.
Or go to settings --> Apps --> your_app --> Clear Data to reset the app and force it to recreate the database and table as you want it.

Comment: Oh Sorry I am getting confused a lot lol , when I cleared Data in settings , the app crashes now is it because I didn't upgrade the db version ?

Comment: Also, you are missing a space in `DROP IF TABLE EXISTS` statement. So, that's probably the actual error

Comment: The errors are obviously your statements, please be careful what you are actually writing! and see my comments below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add spaces here before each type:

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
        COL1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
        COL2 + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+
        COL3 + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"+
        COL4 + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"+
        COL5 + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";
```

And Remove `ID`

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgrade your db version ??

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;//from 1 to 2
private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
OpenHelper(Context context) // constructor
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{

  //Changes in db mentioned here
}
}
```

Comment: Euuu you mean I should create the new table inside onUpgrade method ?

Comment: @bill Yes, you need to DROP and CREATE in thar method. Most tutorials show this

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the actual SQL until you get comfortable with String concatenation.

`CREATE TABLEfoodlist_data (ID ID INTEGER`

You need spaces around the table name, and you put `ID` twice. (You should name it  as `_id`  anyway)

[What is the use of BaseColumns in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899720/what-is-the-use-of-basecolumns-in-android)

Comment: You can always just use the Android Room Persistence library and forget explicitly creating your table