# Kotlin interface implementation behaviour when consuming Java interface

Tags: java, android, kotlin

If I have an interface in Kotlin:

```
interface KotlinInterface {
    val id: String
}
```

I can implement it like so:

```
class MyClass : KotlinInterface {
    override val id: String = "id"
}
```

However, if I were to consume a Java interface like this:

```
public interface JavaInterface {
    String id = "id";
}
```

I cannot override the `id` class variable in a similar way:

```
class MyClass : JavaInterface {
    override val myId: String = JavaInterface.id //linter says: 'myId' overrides nothing
}
```

I also cannot make use of `id` elsewhere despite it having a predefined value:

```
class MyClass : JavaInterface {
    val myArray: Array<String> = arrayOf(id) // linter would say that id is not defined rather than recognising it as the string “id”
}
```

It appears I have to use it like so:

```
class MyClass {
    val id: String = JavaInterface.id
    val myArray: Array<String> = arrayOf(id)
}
```

Could anyone explain this difference in behaviour and point out anything I may be understanding wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot override the id class variable in a similar way:

You can't do it in Java either; the equivalent would be

```
class MyClass implements JavaInterface {
    @Override String getMyId() {
        return JavaInterface.id;
    }
}
```

`getMyId` doesn't override anything.

And if you write in Java

```
class MyClass implements JavaInterface {
    String id = JavaInterface.id;
}
```

you aren't overriding anything, because you can't override fields (in addition, `MyClass.id` is a non-final instance package-private field, while `JavaInterface.id` is implicitly a final static public field because interfaces don't allow any other kind).

> I also cannot make use of id elsewhere despite it having a predefined value:

Again, same as in Java; you need `JavaInterface.id` in both Java and Kotlin, or `import some.package.JavaInterface.id` to use just `id` (`import static` in Java).

There *is* a difference if `MyClass` implements `JavaInterface`, because then in Java you can refer to `JavaInterface.id` as `MyClass.id` or as `someInstanceOfMyClass.id`; and inside `MyClass` just as `id`. But this is often considered a misfeature, so Kotlin's designers avoided it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that last part about referring to the implemented parent interface's initialised variables from within the child class being a "misfeature"? It seems to make sense.

Comment: See e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/49572/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-have-an-interface-to-define-constants and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html.

Comment: Thank you, I found the second link particularly helpful. A part of the quote in the first link states, "It is of no consequence to the users of a class that the class implements a constant interface." Yet, wouldn't users of `MyClass` have access to `MyClass().id` if it implements `JavaInterface`?

Comment: Also, my question arose from the existence of this interface: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html. Is it good practice to use it not by "Constant Interface Antipattern" & abusing inheritance, but rather, to simply write something similar to `val id: String = JavaInterface.id`?

Comment: Regarding the second part of your main answer, I've just realised that I forgot to implement `JavaInterface` as part of my 5th code snippet. I've edited it; the original edit was made on mobile and the mistake wasn't apparent at the time. It is as you said, though. It seems I'm unable to access `id` from within `MyClass`, such as in `arrayOf(id)`, in **Kotlin**.

Comment: 1. "Yet, wouldn't users of MyClass have access to MyClass().id if it implements JavaInterface" Being able to call static methods/access static fields on instances is a second but related misfeature, also absent in Kotlin. I think the consensus it's bad is actually more universal than calling `MyClass.id`: IDEs generally warn about it by default and the Java compiler has a lint warning for it.

Comment: 2. The preferred solution if you want to access `id` without a prefix is `import some.package.JavaInterface.id`, or `import some.package.JavaInterface.*` for all constants.

Comment: In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7900591/11536796) case, I think the custom class I’m creating will need to have a public string `_id`, and I could do it by referencing `BaseColumns._id` once without an import. The answer is pretty old and is for Java, however, so it says it’s possible to do this via implementing the interface of constants, though I now understand that this is not the case in Kotlin.

Answer (score 4):

In the java interface, every variable is a static final variable and static variables can't be overridden.
That is why you see that lint warning.

Edit 1:

Kotlin interface

```
  interface Ser {
       var name: String //abstract
    }
```

is Equivalent to java interface

```
public interface Ser {
   @NotNull
   String getName();

   void setName(@NotNull String var1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I’ve edited my question just as two answers rolled in. If my understanding is correct, Kotlin doesn’t allow interface properties to be initialised with a value at all, while this is possible in Java. However,  if I don’t “shadow” or “replace” that final Java property in my Kotlin implementation, I cannot access the property (which already has a value in Java) by name from within the implementation.

Comment: Yes when you declare a variable without initializing it, its marked as an abstract variable. and in byte code, kotlin creates getter and setter methods for that variable internally so you can override that variable.

Comment: to see how it does just declare the interface with one abstract variable and see its decompiled byte code.

Answer (score 0):

You declared constant (public static String id = "id") at Java interface.

Whereas Kotlin interface declared abstract property. See Kotlin reference: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/interfaces.html