# What is the _COUNT column for?

Tags: android

Android specifies the super-handy `_id` column in the `BaseColumns` interface, usage of which is very well explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899720/what-is-the-use-of-basecolumns-in-android), but what is `_count` for? Count of rows in a directory, what directory?

```
public interface BaseColumns
{
    /**
     * The unique ID for a row.
     * <P>Type: INTEGER (long)</P>
     */
    public static final String _ID = "_id";

    /**
     * The count of rows in a directory.
     * <P>Type: INTEGER</P>
     */
    public static final String _COUNT = "_count";
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why/Should we implement BaseColumns when using a Content Provider in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792554/why-should-we-implement-basecolumns-when-using-a-content-provider-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in [this tutorial](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html):

> Every provider can also report the number of records returned as the _COUNT column; its value is the same for all rows.
>
> Here is an example result set for the query in the previous section:

```
_ID  _COUNT   NAME           NUMBER
44   3        Alan Vain      212 555 1234
13   3        Bully Pulpit   425 555 6677
53   3        Rex Cars       201 555 4433
```