# How to use _COUNT in BaseColumns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've been reading up on `BaseColumns`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BaseColumns.html) in Android to help structure my database schema.

I know that `_ID` is a unique identifier for the row that you have to create yourself:

```
protected static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( " + 
        _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT" +  ...;
```

I also read that `_COUNT` is used to refer to the number of rows in a table.

However, when I tried using `_COUNT`, I got an error. Here is what I tried:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = TimetableDbHelper.getInstance(context).getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.query(
        SubjectsSchema.TABLE_NAME,
        new String[] {SubjectsSchema._COUNT},
        null, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SubjectsSchema._COUNT));
cursor.close();
return count;
```

I'm not sure whether or not this is the correct way to use it, but I got this error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _count (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _count FROM subjects

How should I be using `_COUNT`?

Comment: Your create statement doesn't have a `_count` column. By implementing `BaseColumns`, you simply have access to those values in the schema class. How are you expecting that to map into a SQL creation statement?

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand that, but how should I add it to my database. Should I just add it like any other normal column?

Comment: Does this post answer the question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792554/why-should-we-implement-basecolumns-when-using-a-content-provider-in-android/12946061#12946061

Comment: From what I am reading, it is really only needed if you want to expose a ContentProvider. I'm not sure what will happen when you add the column yourself, but you'll probably have to manually update the table every time there is an insert or delete.

Comment: @cricket_007 That's what I am unsure of - do I need to update count manually? I'm just about to try it out in my code to see what happens (I probably should have done this earlier).

Comment: @cricket_007 Yep, looks like it needs to be updated manually.

Comment: Try `SELECT Count(*) AS _Count FROM subjects`

Comment: @cricket_007 Your point about how `_COUNT` isn't really needed unless I'm using a `ContentProvider` reminded me that I could just use `cursor.getCount()` as I'm not using a `ContentProvider`. This worked for me, but I'm still curious about how `_COUNT` actually works.

Comment: Did you read my comment?

Comment: Thanks, @Rotwang . I'll try it out later on and let you know how it works out.

Comment: It should work just fine. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_useful_functions.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the database, there is nothing special about either `_id` or `_count`.

Your queries return an `_id` or `_count` column when the table is defined to have such a column, or when the query explicitly computes it.

Many objects of the Android framework expect a cursor to have a unique `_id` column, so many tables define it.

In most places, the `_count` is not expected to be present, so it is usually not implemented. And if it is actually needed, it can simply be computed with a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT _id,
       [other fields],
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable) AS _count
FROM MyTable
WHERE ...
```

If you want to find out the size of your own table, you are not required to use the `_count` name; you can execute a query like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM subjects`, or, even simpler, use a [helper function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String)) that does this for you.